# Search & Update MySQL With Form

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I'm trying to put together a form that I can use to search for member details from a mySQL database, retrieve the results so that they appear in pre-determined text boxes on the same form and make updates to send back to the database.

The code I'm using is as follows:

**PHP**

```
<?php 
require("phpfile.php"); 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server 

$connection=mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password); 
if (!$connection) { die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 

// Set the active MySQL database 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection); 
if (!$db_selected) { 
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$email = $_POST['email']; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$emailaddress%'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{ 
echo $row['forename']; 
echo $row['surname']; 
echo "<br />"; 
} 
?>
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">      
  <p>Search: 
    <input name="emailaddress" type="text" id="emailaddress" />
    <br />     
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />     
</p>
  <p>
    <label>
    <input name="forename" type="text" id="forename" value="<?php echo $forename; ?>"  />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="surname" type="text" id="surname" value="<?php echo $surname; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;  </p>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the email address to search for the desired record, but the problem I'm having is that all of the records are retrieved rather than the one I have entered the details for, and the results don't appear in the forename and surname fields on the form.

Could someone perhaps please show me what I'm doing wrong

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... but if you press submit button to update white email it should look like this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['forename']);
$sname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
$emai= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
mysql_query(UPDATE `table` SET `forename` = $fname, `surname` = $sname, `email`=$email WHERE id = `id`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've called the variable "$email" not "$emailaddress". Change your query to be:

```
SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE emailaddress like '%$email%'
```

Previously, your query was searching for an email address like "%%" - which will find every email address.

On another note, you must look into SQL injection. It's one of the most common security risks affecting web applications, yet is very easy to protect against. I won't explain in detail but, for the moment, replace your line:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

With:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Here's more information about SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: im not sore about what irhm really wants

Comment: Hi, apologies if I've not been as clear as I should have been. I have a form whereby I type in a users email address, I then submit that information to a mySQL database table to retrieve the forename and surname for the pertinent record. I would like retrieved forename and surname values to populate the forename and surname text boxes on the same search form. I'll then build upon this and use the same form to make changes to users records and save the amended information back to the database table. I hope this helps. Kind regards

Comment: Have you changed the variable name in your query to '$email'?

Comment: For ease, I've just called everything 'emailaddress' so that I can hopefully get this to work and spend sometime to understand the process.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should escape the POST input before using it. If you're using MySQL, you may use the mysql_real_escape_string() function:

   ```
   $emailaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])
   ```
2. You may populate the form with the retrieved values setting the value parameter in each form input. For security reasons, make sure the output will convert HTML entities:

   ```
   <input name="surname" type="text" id="surname" value="<?php echo isset($surname) ? htmlentities($surname) : null; ?>" />
   ```

You may read the above line as: is $surname set? If so, apply htmlentities and output. Otherwise, return null.